# Chat FAQ auto inlining condition unclear

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I found a little inconvenience: in the FAQ it says: "Some links will be automatically inlined if posted on a single line by themselves [...]" but if I write Text in the chatbox and enter a new line by pressing Shift+Enter and then enter a valid link it will not be inlined. If this is intention you should change the text in the FAQ.

For me forcing a line break using Shift+Enter and then pasting a valid link makes them look like on a single line for themselves but I without auto inlining...

Just a small thing...but it got me

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed a while ago.

Using Shift+Enter with most links will still inline.